# Evento al actualizar un Slider JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Quiero ejecutar un código cada vez que se actualice un `Slider JavaFX` pero sólo cuando se deje de mover su deslizador (`thumb`) con el ratón. He probado con los eventos `OnMouseExited` y `OnMouseDragReleased` pero ninguno funciona.

¿Qué evento necesito usar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando pulsamos con el ratón sobre el `thumb` de un control `Slider` con el fin de modificar su valor, los eventos que se generan son los siguientes:

1. `OnMousePressed` cuando pulsamos el ratón
2. `OnMouseDragged` en caso de que deslicemos su `thumb`
3. `OnMouseReleased` cuando dejamos de pulsar el ratón
4. `OnMouseClicked` justo después del anterior evento

Si quieres ejecutar un código justo en el momento de soltar el ratón necesitas captar el evento `OnMouseReleased`. Es aquí donde tienes que colocar cualquier código que actualice o modifique otros `Slider` para evitar un reajuste contínuo de éstos (y posiblemente un parpadeo molesto) antes de llegar al valor deseado.